# I'm trying to give out the values of my Database in my PHP, but I keep getting: 0 results

Tags: php, sql

This is in my `Db` class inside a `classDb.php`

```
public function select($colName,$table)
   {
$sql = "SELECT ($colName) FROM '$table' Or 1=1";
       $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
       if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
           // output data of each row
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. " - Toggl_cid: " . $row["toggl_cid"]. "<br>";
           }
       } else {
           echo "0 results";
       }
       $this->conn->close();
}
```

calling the function from `Db` class to my `project` class inside a `classProject.php` File

```
    public function select(){
        $this->Db->select('id', `name`, 'toggl_cid', 'project');
    }
```

and then running the function in my `index.php`

```
$project = new Project();
$project-> select();
```

so basically as a result I get `0 results` even though I already have the right col names table name and already have 2 rows of data in my database.

Comment: `'$table'` should not be in single quotes

Comment: `\`name\`` should throw an error. This should be normal quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending table name as second parameter
Like
`public function select(){ $this->Db->select('*', 'project'); }`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Dharman and @Rishni both of your answers helped me on some error
i corrected those and had to give my `$colName` a string Like this.

```
$colName =  "id, name, toggl_cid";
$this->Db->select($colName, 'project');
```